# Proving the limit of a piece wise function does not exist

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I found this example in my calculus notes:

> The function
> $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
>                                    1 & \text{if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$} \\
>                                    0 & \text{if $x\notin\mathbb{Q}$} 
>   \end{cases}$$
> has no limit at $x=0$. Actually, $f$ has no limit at any point. The proof is left as an exercise.

I have been trying to solve it but I haven't been able. I think the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{I}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ might be useful. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Take any $x$. By density, for all positive integers $n$, there exists a rational $r_n$ such that $|x-r_n|<\frac{1}{n}$. Similarly, there exists an irrational $y_n$ such that $|x-y_n|<\frac{1}{n}$. Prove that $r_n \to x$ and $y_n\to x$. What is happening in the limits of $f(r_n)$ and $f(y_n)$?

Comment: Thank you! The Archimedean Property is useful to prove that $r_n\to x$ and $y_n\to x$, right?